# Cannot post request to localdomain 127.0.0.1:80 in RHEL7 while setting up Mainflux

Tags: rhel, iot

I am trying to setup Mainflux on my Linux RHEL 7 Server. While doing `mainflux-cli provision test` it shows an error as:

```
Post http://localhost/users: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
```

I have tried following:

Wget:

```
wget 127.0.0.1
--2020-04-02 09:52:01--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

Traceroute:

```
traceroute 127.0.0.1
traceroute to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.062 ms  0.029 ms  0.027 ms
```

Ping:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
87 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 86006ms
```

Can anyone help with configuring this.
How to check if Mainflux is running, and if running then on which url.

Comment: Please include the output of `netstat -atlpn | grep :80`

Comment: @Panki it shows nothig for `netstat -atlpn | grep :80`

Comment: In that case, your service is either not running, or running on another port.